# polymorphic relationship is giving a blank page when running in laravel 8

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I'm new to Laravel 8, and I'm trying to do a polymorphic relation among three models. I've followed the documentation step by step, and I finally got a working page but without any data (blank page).

Any answer will be much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: please provide code

Comment: Hello @Bassem, Are you migrating from Laravel 7 to Laravel 8?

Comment: Hi @GABYKARAM, yes I am following a tutorial on Udemy from Edwin Diaz but the tutorial is following Laravel 7, and it's not updated to follow Laravel 8.

For the previous chapters, I solved the errors by myself by googling the solution but now I  am stuck and I wasn't able to find the solution for this specific error.

Comment: ok that is great, I also learned about Laravel from the same tutorial and I know what is your problem, I am gonna write it below in the answer section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so in the difference between Laravel 7 and 8 is that the model namespace was changed from `App`to Àpp\Models`.

So try to change the column data where you have something like `App\Post`, `App\Media` or `App\User` to `App\Models\Post`, `App\Models\Media` or `App\Models\User`

Comment: Thanks @GABYKARAM it works for me when i directly changed the namespaces in my database.